# How to store a bidirectional relationship between two variables as a third variable?

Tags: rust

I have an array of nations, and I want to generate the relationship between those nations, so that the relationship between nation A and nation B is always identical to the relationship between nation B and nation A.

For example, Japan and Ecuador have a relationship value of 15. I want to be able to run both `get_relationship("Japan", "Ecuador");` and `get_relationship("Ecuador", "Japan");` and always get `15`. Ideally, I don't want to have to store this value twice, as I don't want to have to bother to keep it in sync.

Below is my current experimental code. Note that I'm storing nations as a `HashMap` of `(name as String, Nation as struct)` for unrelated reasons, mainly so I can pull up the desired `Nation` object by name alone.

```
extern crate rand;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use rand::Rng;

struct Nation;

pub struct NationManager {
    nations: HashMap<String, Nation>, // The string is the nation's name
    rels: HashMap<String, HashMap<String, i8>>, // Again, both Strings are names
}

impl NationManager {
    fn generate_relationships(&mut self) {
        let mut random_rel: i8 = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
        for (source, _) in &self.nations {
            for (target, _) in &self.nations {
                if source > target {
                    self.rels
                        .get(source)
                        .expect("ERROR")
                        .insert(target.clone(), random_rel);
                } else if source < target {
                    self.rels
                        .get(target)
                        .expect("ERROR")
                        .insert(source.clone(), random_rel);
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

I don't think this is the best way to achieve the desired result, and it doesn't compile at the moment; is it actually possible to nest two `for` loops like this?

```
error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:19:21
   |
19 |                       self.rels
   |  _____________________^ starting here...
20 | |                         .get(source)
21 | |                         .expect("ERROR")
   | |________________________________________^ ...ending here: cannot borrow as mutable

error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:24:21
   |
24 |                       self.rels
   |  _____________________^ starting here...
25 | |                         .get(target)
26 | |                         .expect("ERROR")
   | |________________________________________^ ...ending here: cannot borrow as mutable
```

Comment: An unrelated note: Instead of `.expect("ERROR")`, you might as well use `.unwrap()`, which is easier on the eyes. The point of `expect()` is to provide a meaningful error message.

Comment: What is the actual error message provided by the compiler? "Doesn't compile due to ownership shenanigans" is not very useful.

Comment: @user4815162342 I reiterate, "current experimental code".
@E_net4 "cannot borrow as mutable", pointing at `self.rels.get(target).expect("ERROR")`.
I was kind of hoping someone would have a better solution. I cannot imagine this is how I am meant to be achieving this task.

Comment: Please edit your question to include further content.

Comment: Sure! What content are you after?

Comment: I meant that you should include the compiler's error message (as precise as possible) in the question, and not in the comments.

Comment: @Quintus: By the way, shouldn't the random generation be *in the loop*? It seems that all countries will end up with an equal relationship score here.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Well spotted! Mea culpa. I never managed to get my code to run, so I didn't pick up on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First things first: the issue you have is that `get` returns an immutable reference, and you try to `insert` in there. You would want to use `get_mut` to get a mutable reference on which `insert` can be performed.

---

However I would recommend altering the design:

1. Storing a map name -> ID,
2. Using ID as the key in the other maps.

The main advantage of this scheme being that numerical IDs are much cheaper/efficient than Strings.

```
pub struct NationManager {
    last_id: u32,
    name_to_id: HashMap<String, u32>,
    relationships: HashMap<(u32, u32), i8>, // (smaller ID, larger ID) -> score
}
```

Performing a look-up of the relationship between two countries will involve knowing their IDs (two look-ups in `name_to_id`) and then looking up the relationship score.

The flattening of `relationships` would *tremendously* simplify your generation step as well:

```
impl NationManager {
    fn generate_relationships(&mut self) {
        let random_rel: i8 = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101);
        for source in 0..self.last_id {
            for target in (source + 1)..self.last_id {
                self.relationships.insert((source, target), random_rel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: actually, a domain analysis could let us use a much smaller ID as well; you shouldn't need more than 65,535 nations, so `u16` is definitely sufficient, and it's likely that `u8` (255 nations) would be sufficient as as well (there are 193 nations registered in the UN).*

Comment: "you should need more than 65,535 nations"? :)

Comment: That's a really clever solution, thank you! Using numbers definitely makes this easier to wrap my head around. So, for the getter, I can assume that the relationship between any two nations is stored in a `(lower ID, higher ID)` tuple, right? Also, thanks for pointing out the `get_mut` method - I'm still wrapping my head around ownership in Rust.

Comment: FWIW, using a `u8` / `u16` / `u32` [all seem to have the same struct size](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=d4dba07dc00e07ce1c1a0b97d7e45281&version=undefined) - 88 bytes.

Comment: @Shepmaster: a `Vec<u8>` and a `Vec<u32>` will also have the same size, but its heap allocated array will have a different size. The same holds for `HashMap` (baring padding). Of course, since the buffer is internal it's a bit harder to check, and I am not sure whether `HashMap` is taking advantage of smaller keys. Bluss' OrderedMap would as it uses a separate `Vec<(K, V)>`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the wrong method. [`HashMap::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) does not allow you to mutate the result:

```
fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V> 
    where K: Borrow<Q>,
          Q: Hash + Eq,
```

You want [`get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut):

```
fn get_mut<Q: ?Sized>(&mut self, k: &Q) -> Option<&mut V> 
    where K: Borrow<Q>,
          Q: Hash + Eq,
```