# Should I choose the minimum integer size as much as possible?

Tags: rust

While there are many integer types in Rust such as `i32` and `u8`, I am not sure which type should I choose in terms of writing performant code. For example, which code is better in performance, A or B?

```rust
// A
let x: u8 = 1;
let must_be_i32: i32 = x as i32 + 1;
// B
let x: i32 = 1;
let must_be_i32: i32 = x + 1;
```

I am always writing like A to use less memory but writing type conversion so many times is tedious and feeling what am I doing is meaningless...

So my question is when to use singned/unsigned and i8/i6...i128 types.

Comment: *"which code is better in performance?"* - this is a poor example since the optimizer would const-eval this away. But anyway, `x as i32` is a no-op as far as a modern CPU is concerned (just a different load instruction). If you're interested in performance, a smaller integer size *may* reduce memory pressure and improve cache friendliness, but won't really improve numerical speed (unless your operations can be vectorized). And I only say "may" because alignment and padding around your reduced integers may prove the point moot.

Comment: If your thinking is *"1 is smaller than 256, so my variable should be u8 to reduce memory usage"* you should probably stop doing that. Especially if we're only talking about local variables.

Comment: "Premature optimization" - textbook example of it.

Comment: Remark: Here a new book for optimizing Rust (compile/run time), written for intermediate and advanced programmers: https://nnethercote.github.io/perf-book/type-sizes.html#smaller-integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at least not for the reasons you seem to be describing.

You should be selecting your integer type based on the *domain* of values it represents, and not based on the *value* of a particular instance. An obvious one is the domain of lengths, capacities, and indexes: `usize`. A timestamp? Often `u64`. Bytes? clearly `u8`. Windows' cursor and window positions? Happen to be `i32`. Blockchain balances? `u256` (not Rust native). If you're doing lots of numerical operations, you should consider the space of values those operations should work under. `i32` is a decent starting point but you can obviously go higher if required.

You will likely uncover the domain naturally by *not* explicitly typing what integer type it is and instead letting the compiler infer what it should be. The only time you should be using `as` is when those domains intersect.

This has mostly been guidance that's not particularly performance framed but the reason for that is there is no point optimizing the integer size of local variables. The compiler has the most visibility into the values and operations done within a function and thus will make its own choices how to achieve that.

For a more concrete justification, this "integer size optimized" function:

```
pub fn f(data: &[i32; 1024]) {
    let offset: u8 = 5;
    for i in 0u8..100u8 {
        let value = data[i as usize] + offset as i32;
        std::hint::black_box(value);
    }
}
```

Compiles to the **exact same instructions** as the natural version:

```
pub fn f(data: &[i32; 1024]) {
    let offset = 5;
    for i in 0..100 {
        let value = data[i] + offset;
        std::hint::black_box(value);
    }
}
```

Choosing `u8` for these types did not save any memory. Note: `black_box` was used to avoid the loop being optimized away completely.

Now, are there cases where local integer size *could* affect performance? Sure its possible in a function more complicated than I've shown above that smaller integers could reduce the stack frame size or change instructions emitted such that the binary is smaller. But your program performance would much more likely be bottlenecked by cache pressure from your in-memory data structures or some other limiting factor far more than any effects from local variable size of integers would.

Related: [Am I casting integer types too much?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481325)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and comments. Both of them helped me understand the cost of ops and optimizations. Deciding integral types based on domains is very clear to me too.

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with having to choose between integral types when I started with Rust. In C/C++ there is a clear default, which is `int`. In Rust I recommend (and I think this is the community consensus) to use `i32` as the default, unless there is a good reason to use something else.